# Python if statement executes on false, and true

Tags: python

I am having trouble with some if statements in my script. I run from a terminal using `./iojson.py "nodev"`, but the code still executes the if statements for `"enum"` or `"snum"`, which cause my script to stop due to a `NameError`.

The code is below:

```
devicelist = sys.argv[1]
if devicelist == "snum" or "enum":
    if devicelist == "snum":
        print("It executed snum")
        with open('SNUM.txt') as f:
            content = f.readlines()
    if devicelist == "enum":
        print("It executed enum")
        with open('ENUM.txt') as f:
            content = f.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() for x in content]
    devices = ''.join(content)
    data['attachments'].append({
        'fields' : [{
            'title' : 'Serial numbers:',
            'value' : devices
            }]
        })
elif devicelist == "nodev":
    print("It executed nodev")
    pass
```

After execution, the response is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./iojson.py", line 43, in <module>
    content = [x.strip() for x in content]
NameError: name 'content' is not defined
```

My understanding though is that it should never have gotten to the `content` variable in the first place. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well firstly this is not doing what you think: `if devicelist == "snum" or "enum":`, it's going to evaluate to true on the second `or` condition as it's viewed as `or 'enum'` which converts the string to `True`, you want `if devicelist == "snum" or devicelist == "enum":` secondly where is context defined here?

Comment: @EdChum youre right for the `if` but you have read context instead of `content` and its value is `content = f.readlines()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if devicelist == "snum" or "enum":
```

will always be true.

This is what the compiler will check:

```
if (devicelist == "snum") or "enum":
```

The first check is `False`, while the second check for casting `"enum"` to a boolean is always `True`.

Workaround:

```
if devicelist in ("snum", "enum"):
```